# Font awesome 5 : cannot display arrow-alt-circle-up

Tags: font-awesome-5

I wonder why the icon :  arrow-alt-circle-up does not display...
in the same div I display the user icon wo any problem...
arrow-alt-circle-up icon is lsited in v5 Free icons...

```
     <h2>Test jQuery().animate()</h2>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
      <div class="col-4"></div>
      <div class="col-4" id="scrollTop">
        <div class="align-items-center justify-content-end">
           <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
           <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i>To Top
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

[image: icon display]

UPDATE

I did some tests in jsFiddle , and I can get fas fa-arrow-up
but this does not work also inside my html code...

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erwin16/4wnwg0sk/)

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED ... forget to add it into fontawesome.library ... I am using v5 !

```
    import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome'
    import faArrowCircleUp from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid/faArrowAltCircleUp'

    fontawesome.library.add(faArrowCircleUp)

    <div class="align-items-center justify-content-end">
      <div class="fa-2x">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i>To Top
     </div>
```